# Bootstrap Modal Field not expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Modal that is using jQuery to create a list for me within my form. I'm just wanting to have the email section expand as the length of the email input is expanded.

Update: here is the modal that I am using: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=table-with-add-and-delete-row-feature

This is the list when I first input the field:

[image]

I want to be able to push the column width on the length of the email input.

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
.table-wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 30px auto;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px; 
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    }
    .table-title {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
    .table-title h2 {
        margin: 6px 0 0;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .table-title .add-new {
        float: right;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 13px;
    }
 .table-title .add-new i {
  margin-right: 4px;
 }
    table.table {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
        border-color: #e9e9e9;
    }
    table.table th i {
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    table.table th:last-child {
        width: 100px;
    }
    table.table td a {
  cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 5px;
  min-width: 24px;
    }    
 table.table td a.add {
        color: #27C46B;
    }
    table.table td a.edit {
        color: #FFC107;
    }
    table.table td a.delete {
        color: #E34724;
    }
    table.table td i {
        font-size: 19px;
    }
 table.table td a.add i {
        font-size: 24px;
     margin-right: -1px;
        position: relative;
        top: 3px;
    }    
    table.table .form-control {
        height: 32px;
        line-height: 32px;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
 table.table .form-control.error {
  border-color: #f50000;
 }
 table.table td .add {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<!-- Modal (THIS IS WHAT CONTROLS THE MODAL) -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Users &amp; Email Addresses</h5>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>User Role</th>
                          <th>Actions</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="modalTBody">
                  
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add more details in your code.

Comment: Why is someone downvoting? Please let me know what I'm doing to deserve the downvote.. I followed the format.

Comment: Hey @DhavalJardosh, the modal that I have included is what is controlling the sizing.

Comment: Hi @DhavalJardosh, here is the modal that I am using: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=table-with-add-and-delete-row-feature

Comment: https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/EREaOO?editors=1000, this is what it looks like to me. What are you expecting it to look like?

Comment: Yes that is what I want, I want the column to stay small if email is test@gmail.com and expand when the email passes the standard size gsdfhgsethsghsdghjgjgj@gmail.com

Comment: You can use `width:fit-content`, let me show you in example. 
"Width of column should be equal to the longest email", please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173490/discussion-between-saintlouis-events-and-dhaval-jardosh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out!

The Modal's CDN CSS was defining this attribute:

```
table.table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

I changed it to:

```
table.table {
    table-layout: auto;
}
```

Works perfectly.